# iPhone SDK reload UIView's content

Tags: iphone, uiview, refresh, uilabel

I have two views, one view takes the whole screen, the second view covers only a little portion.  What I want is for that second view to be on the first view (which I already have done), but the problem is, when I set values (in this case UILabel's) the label on the screen doesn't display that new value.  I know for a fact the method gets called, but for some reason it won't change the label's value.

Edit:  Here's the code:

```
-(void)loadHighScores
{   
[no1 setText:@"test"];
 NSLog(@"it works");
}
```

And here's how I call it:

```
    highscore = [[HighScore alloc] init];
    [highscore loadHighScores];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
[myView setNeedsDisplay];
```

Quote from Apple docs:

> By default, geometry changes to a view
>   automatically redisplays the view
>   without needing to invoke the
>   drawRect:  method. Therefore, you need
>   to request that a view redraw only
>   when the data or state used for
>   drawing a view changes. In this case,
>   send the view the setNeedsDisplay 
>   message. Any UIView objects marked as
>   needing display are automatically
>   redisplayed when the application
>   returns to the run loop.

Comment: In that case, can you post some more details of your code? How do you know for a fact that the labels are being set?

Comment: I NSLoged the method that is being called

Comment: Code please. The fact that you're loggingthe method in which the labels should be set doesn't prove they are set